# Unable to print the website status after the 1st URL in the given list using Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, csv

This is the Python file that checks the given CSV file that contains the web url's and their status is ok or not found:

```py
import csv
import requests
from http import HTTPStatus
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


def get_websites(csv_path: str) -> list[str]:
    """Loads websites from a csv file"""

    websites: list[str] = []
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            if 'https://' not in row[1]:
                websites.append(f'https://{row[1]}')
            else:
                websites.append(row[1])

    return websites


def get_user_agent() -> str:
    """Returns a user agent that can be used with requests"""

    ua = UserAgent()
    return ua.chrome


def get_status_description(status_code: int) -> str:
    """Uses the status code to return a readable description"""

    for value in HTTPStatus:
        if value == status_code:
            description: str = f'({value} {value.name}) {value.description}'
            return description

    return '(???) Unknown status code...'


def check_website(website: str, user_agent: str):
    """Gets that status code for a website and prints the result"""
    try:
       # code: int = requests.get(website, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent}).status_code
        response = requests.get(website, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})
        code: int = response.status_code
        print(website, get_status_description(code))
    except Exception as e:
       # print(f'**Could not get information for website: "{website}"')
       print("Exception is: ", e)


def main():
    sites: list[str] = get_websites('websites.csv')
    user_agent: str = get_user_agent()

    # Check websites
    for i, site in enumerate(sites):
        check_website(site, user_agent)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

csv file:

```
1,"apple.com"
2,"facebook.com"
3,"lulumall.com"
4,"newgrounds.com"
5,"linkedin.com"
6,"python-guide.com"
7,"fastmail.com"
8,"soundcloud.com"
9,"whatsapp.com/hello"
10,"udemy.com"
```

Output:

```
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='linkedin.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='lulumall.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] 
EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)')))
https://apple.com (200 OK) Request fulfilled, document follows
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='linkedin.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='python-guide.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fastmail.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='soundcloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='whatsapp.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /hello (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
Exception is:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='udemy.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
```

If I keep all the URLs as apple.com, then it is working even you change the order of apple.com url. It is not working for all the other URLs except apple.com.

Could anyone help me.

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Do you know [How to step through Python code to help debug issues](/q/4929251/4518341)? Please make a [mre] to isolate the problem. For example, if the CSV is being parsed correctly, just include `sites`, not everything that went into making it. For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: The code doesn't even tell you what exception you're getting! Try removing the try-except and seeing what that tells you.

Comment: FWIW, the `try` blocks could be smaller so that they don't catch exceptions they shouldn't. It looks like the one in `check_website` could be `try: response = requests.get(...)` then in an `else` block you can do `code: int = response.status_code` and then the `print`. Same for the one in `get_status_description`; it looks like it could be `try: status = HTTPStatus(status_code)` then in `else`: `return f'({status_code} {status.name}) {status.description}'`

Comment: Apologies, I didn't get what you are saying @wjandrea as I'm new to python.

Comment: What part? You can ignore my whole last comment, if it helps.

Comment: The first step is to replace your exception handling with something that prints the actual error, i.e. `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: Hi @DavidWaterworth, After that what to do?

Comment: Also don't try and do two things at once, instead of `code: int = requests.get(website, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent}).status_code` make it two lines, i.e. `repsonse = requests.get(website, headers={'User-Agent': user_agent})` and then `code = response.status_code`

Comment: @Vamsi then run again and edit the question with the error message. You generally need to use a "divide and conquer" approach when debugging.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth, Updated the Code as well as output which gave me a detailed exception.